# Operational Semantics in prolog

Tags: prolog

My question is quite simple and iI understand what I have to do, but it seems like I can't represent my understanding. How to write predicates to define gates such as XOR or NOR in terms of a NAND gate rules?

for example :

```
nand(t,t,f).
nand(t,f,t).
nand(f,t,t).
nand(f,f,t).
```

Above is a truth table for nand gate. Now if I want to define XOR gate using the above terms in Prolog, for example I need to ask Prolog about XOR(X,Y,Z) , it would give me three possible answers, how should I build a predicate to define it?

Thank You

Comment: See the answer @CapelliC gave on this. You just need to first use boolean logic to write out (or "wire up") the desired operation in terms of the given operations. He showed how to get XOR from NAND inputs. If you want NOR, you would use boolean logic again. NAND is `NOT(A AND B)`. NOR is `NOT(A OR B)`. Use logical rules such as `NOT(A OR B)` is equivalent to `(NOT A) AND (NOT B)`. How do you get `NOT A` from NAND? Easy: `NOT A = NAND(A, A)`. Do a little work from there to figure out `nor(A, B, C)`.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't writing Prolog statements in my prior comment. They are just logical statements. But the information should be sufficient for you to solve your problem if you give it some thought.

Answer (score 2):

The difficult part is to devise the expression in terms of a nand gate. Let's say we trust [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43342/22126): a solution then could be

```
xor(A,B,C) :-
    nand(A,B,O1),
     nand(A,O1,O21),
     nand(B,O1,O22),
      nand(O21,O22,C).
```

test:

```
?- setof(X/Y/Z,xor(X,Y,Z),L).
L = [f/f/f, f/t/t, t/f/t, t/t/f].
```